# Phonegap take a photo and copy it 3 times

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm able to take a picture with Phonegap but after, I want to save it 3 times with different name.

Is there an option to copy the photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(<your_file_path>/<file_name>,
     function(fileObj){
         console.log('success! file was found');
         window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, null);

         function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
             var documentsPath = fileSystem.root;
             fileObj.copyTo(documentsPath, <your_given_name>,
             function(entry){
                            console.log('copying was successful');
                            console.log('File Path '+entry.fullPath);
             },
             function(){
                            console.log('unsuccessful copying');
             });
         }
     }, 
     function(){
     console.log('failure! file was not found')
});
```

First replace the `<your_file_path>/<file_name>` with your captured image path and then iterate this code using a for loop and get multiple copy of image.
For further assistance go through this link [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry)